# Class 'Application_Plugin_CheckAuthentication' not found in bootstrap.php in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

I have created a plugin in zend framework and registered this plugin in bootstrap.php. but my page is showing the error

Class 'Application_Plugin_CheckAuthentication' not found in bootstrap.php file.

My plugin registration code is below:

```
    function _initViewHelpers() { 
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_CheckAuthentication());
}
```

I think this is not taking the plugins folder. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: make sure that namespace `Application` is autoloaded. Also double check the casing of the class & file.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the actual file?

If the file is at `/application/plugins` or perhaps `/application/modules/mymodule/plugins` the autolaoder should find it and autload it because `/plugins` is an [autoloaded resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) for **Plugin**.

If you file is any where else you will need to register the path:

```
//in the application.ini
pluginPaths.Application_Plugin = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Application/Plugin"

//in the bootstrap, or anywhere else really.
//there may be other syntax available...
$loader = new Zend_Loader_PluginLoader();
$loader->addPrefixPath($prefix, $path);
```

once the autoloader knows where to look everything should work.